# How to Create RecycleView with custom Shape?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, shapes

I made a RecycleView with a Custom shape like this, but I found it difficult to make a semicircle on the right and left side. what should I add to the .xml file?

[image]

Comment: looks like images used as background.

Comment: back ground image you can use... try using 9 patch image

Comment: You can use one image and change image color based on your condition.

Comment: You can either use any image or check this library for custom view https://github.com/vipulasri/TicketView

Answer (score 2):

You can Use this layout as your row

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >
   <View
       android:layout_width="20dp"
       android:layout_height="20dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_marginStart="-10dp"
       android:background="@drawable/shape_example_circle"
       />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
`enter code here`Make your view here
    </RelativeLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="-10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_example_circle"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The small Circle Drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >
<size android:height="@dimen/dp_20"
    android:width="@dimen/dp_20"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/greyish"/>

</shape>
```