# How do I create a TicketView with a cutout on the top in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-view

I'm working on an Android app and I want to create a custom TicketView with a distinct cutout on the top. I'm using the com.vipulasri:ticketview library, and I have successfully created a basic TicketView. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to add a cutout on the top to give it a unique appearance.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

I've checked the library's documentation, but I couldn't find any specific information on how to create a cutout like this.

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this effect? Do I need to create a custom background drawable, or is there a way to modify the TicketView properties to add this cutout?

I would appreciate any code examples or step-by-step instructions to help me implement this in my Android app. Thanks in advance!

What i have tried:

```
<com.vipulasri.ticketview.TicketView
android:id="@+id/ticketView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:tv_backgroundColor="#FF5733"
app:tv_cornerRadius="4dp"
app:tv_dashHeight="10dp"
app:tv_dashGap="4dp"
app:tv_text="Sample Ticket"
app:tv_textColor="#FFFFFF"
app:tv_textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Just to get the idea see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53475427/6576302

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android TicketView library](https://github.com/passid-services/Android-TicketView) instead. it has a nice property `app:ticketPunchLocation` that you can cutout a half circle from any side you want. For example `app:ticketPunchLocation="top|bottom"` will cutout a half circle from top and bottom. For cutting corners use `app:ticketPunchRadius`.

So in your case use the following (change it according to your goal. play with all feature to reach what you are trying to achieve):

```
<com.passid.android.ticketview.TicketView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        app:ticketBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:ticketCornerType="rounded"
        app:ticketElevation="20dp"
        app:ticketOrientation="vertical"
        app:ticketPunchLocation="top"
        app:ticketPunchRadius="24dp"
        app:ticketShowBorder="false"
        app:ticketShowDivider="true">

<!-- your views  -->

</com.passid.android.ticketview.TicketView>
```

[image]

**Update:**
If the above doesn't worked try to [add the main classes](https://github.com/passid-services/Android-TicketView/tree/master/ticketview/src/main/java/com/passid/android/ticketview) and [its attributes](https://github.com/passid-services/Android-TicketView/blob/master/ticketview/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml) into your project like other classes.

**Update 2:**
You can also use [similar TicketView library](https://github.com/lilincpp/TicketView) that is working fine. [See this example](https://github.com/lilincpp/TicketView/blob/master/TicketDemo/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml): (controll top and bottom circles using `boundary_topItemQuantity` and `boundary_bottomItemQuantity`

```
    <com.lilincpp.ticketview.support.view.TicketView
        android:id="@+id/ticketview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:boundary_bottomItemQuantity="1"
        app:boundary_bottomRadius="24dp"
        app:boundary_hasStroke="true"
        app:boundary_roundCorner="4dp"
        app:boundary_shadowPx="8dp"
        app:boundary_show="left|right|top|bottom"
        app:boundary_strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:boundary_topItemQuantity="1"
        app:boundary_topDrawWeight="0.21"
        app:boundary_topRadius="24dp">
   .... 

   </com.lilincpp.ticketview.support.view.TicketView>
```

Comment: Could not find com.passid.android:ticketview:1.0.0.
Required by:
    project :app
Search in build.gradle files

.  I am getting this error when I use the library that you suggested.

Comment: Try by removing the `com.vipulasri.ticketview.TicketView` library and adding the above library.

Comment: I have done that and still not working, can you tell me where this is hosted so I can add that repository, I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: @vyshnavvyshu: see the update,

Comment: you have given an outdated code as an example